# Compilers and local/global variable

Tags: variables, pointers, compiler-construction, global, local

How does a compiler differentiate between local and global variables when 
converting the code to instruction sequences?

And secondly am i right in thinking the constants are stored with the
instruction set and string are stored via a pointer to a constant block 
of memory?

Comment: The answers to those questions will heavily depend on the language.

Comment: well in general case can you tell me what happens?

Comment: For instance, in C local variables are stored in the stack while globals are stored in the heap.

Comment: Are you asking how the compiler knows whether a variable is global or local or how that difference affects the generated code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer you are looking for is that the compiler scopes the local variable to whatever it is local to (e.g. in a function, the variables in the function would be scoped to the function; in a class, the variables are scoped to the class).  In the case of a global variable the variable is scoped to the program or the system as a whole, I've seen the term used both ways.

Example:

```
program P {
  variable myGlobal

  function F {
    variable myFunction
  }
}
```

In the example above, myGlobal variable would be scoped to all of program P, so function F would be able to see myGlobal.  While myFunction would only be visible in the function F.

Global variables are sometimes used to mean system wide variables (e.g. IP address, OS version, ...).

Scope is a very big topic, you might want to check out the Wikipedia entry on the topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

These might also help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable